# How to elegantly prevent certain elements being rendered on modern browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, browser

So I want to prevent certain elements (e.g. ads banners) which I know their html/css properties, for example, they will have a class like `XXXX-ads-notification`, to be rendered/show up when I browser certain domains?

Currently what I do is, when webpage rendered completely, I ***inspected elements and manually removed*** them, so I can get rid of ads/notifications etc. such annoying things when I view certain pages/domains.

However, it's inefficient, and I need to do it every time, let alone I'd like to handle different situations for different domains.

I am not sure if I need to ***write my own extension*** to handle this, or is there any more brilliant/elegant way to achieve such goal?

BTW, I am using AdBlock, and I am feeling its rule is not very suitable in my cases, because some ads are more fitted into content (e.g. native ads) and may not be captured by this extension…

Since browser stores html files in client side, I actually don’t think it’s a real hack and should be free to do so?

Comment: adblock has it implemented, click the extension icon, then click the ` block element` link, click the element on the page you want to block

Answer (score 1):

I have a [userscript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) which does exactly this. (You'll need a userscript manager like Tampermonkey.) The general idea I'm using is to make a list of CSS selectors that point to ads, and insert a `<style>` tag that sets those elements to `display: none`.

For example, if a site has a class named `ad`, it can be hidden by inserting the following:

```
<style>
.ad {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

This is the full userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Frames
// @namespace    CertainPerformance
// @version      1.0.0
// @match        *://*/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const selectorsToHideStr = `
stackoverflow.com
  .-marketing-link
  .bottom-share-links
  #footer

example.com
  .someOtherAdSelectorOnExampleDotCom
`;
// ADD SITES AND SELECTORS ABOVE AS NEEDED

const selectorsToHideBySite = selectorsToHideStr
  .match(/^.+(?:\n +.+)+/gm)
  .reduce((a, siteStr) => {
    const lines = siteStr.split('\n');
    const site = lines.shift();
    const selector = lines
      .map(str => str.trim())
      .join(', ');
    a[site] = selector;
    return a;
  }, {});

const selectorsToHide = selectorsToHideBySite[window.location.host];
if (selectorsToHide) {
  const styleTextContent = selectorsToHide + ' { display: none !important }';
  document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = styleTextContent;
}
```

To hide an ad on a page, just add to the `selectorsToHideStr`. In the above example, selectors `.-marketing-link`, `.bottom-share-links`, and `#footer` get hidden when on Stack Overflow.

For your example, if site `somesite.com` has ads with the class `XXXX-ads-notification`, you could add this to the `selectorsToHideStr`:

```
somesite.com
  [class$="ads-notification"]
```

which will match and hide elements which have a class name that ends in `ads-notification` when on `somesite.com`.

Comment: Interesting, I like this idea, I am using Tampermonkey but for a totally different purpose lol. But I am curious, Why not just write a javascript statement like childNode.remove() (for example), to directly remove them, in stead of insert more code into page, and hide them? :)

Comment: The problem is *detecting the insertion* of said elements. You would need a deep MutationObserver for such a thing, which is computationally expensive, especially on large pages. Also, `.remove()`ing the ad element may cause other functionality on the page to break if it can't find the ad. In contrast, a style tag is just insert-and-done, nothing else needed.

Comment: Wow, answering an unanswerable super-broad question with real code... Impressive!

Comment: @wOxxOm It's certainly not "unanswerable".

Comment: Well, questions like that are unanswerable in 99% of cases or receive nonsensical and low-quality answers.